Is it possible to identify which indicators influence the credit risk for each client company in credit risk analysis?
I am working on credit risk analysis. I want to predict the risk of each company developing a debt with a fictional company. I obtained the feature importance from the model, but I want to know if it is possible to obtain which indicators influence the risk found for each client company.
For example, client company X has a 70% risk, and this risk is associated with the variables city, age, and number of employees. Another client company Y may have an 80% risk, and the risk is associated with the variables city, service, and average salary.
I am conducting a simple initial analysis with the following steps, where the model is trained with 20 indicators of companies that have already incurred a debt (classification 1) and the same amount of other companies that have not incurred a debt (classification 0). The model is fitted, and then predictions are made for new companies without classification.
# X base composed of encoded indicators
features = df_all_aux.columns.tolist() 
X = df_all_aux[features[:-1]] # all features except "Classification"

# y base composed of the target: 1 if debt, 0 if no debt
y = df_all_aux['Classification']

#Define the model
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)

#Train the model using the training data
rf_classifier.fit(X, y)

#Predictions using the asset data
y_pred = rf_classifier.predict_proba(df_new_companies)

#Incorporating the data into the dataset
df_new_companies['Risk_0'] = y_pred[:, 0]  # Probability of being class 0
df_new_companies['Risk_1'] = y_pred[:, 1]  # Probability of being class 1
 

The dataframe df_all_aux already encoded has the following structure:
City    Age     Number_Employe    Service     Average_Salary     Classification ...

1       100              20000          3               2000                  1

2        85              15000          1               5200                  1

1       103              20100          1               5200                  1

4       100              19800          2               5000                  0

1       101              30000          2               3500                  0

3        92              18900          3               5100                  0
...      

over 1000 rows and 20 columns

df_new_companies has the same structure except that it has a column with the ID of the companies.
I already have the risk percentages, now I just want to know which indicators is most associated with risk 1 for each company.

I believe you are looking for feature_importances_ property. It returns a ndarray of the importance of the features (all features importance values sum to 1). You should zip to it the list of feature names and then you can sort it.

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi Thank you for the response. I researched a bit about the feature_importances_ property and didn't find many studies. Could you give me an example of how I could find the influence of each indicator on each predicted class separately with the function you mentioned?

sorted(list(zip(rf_classifier.feature_names_in_, rf_classifier.feature_importances_)), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

Explanation:

rf_classifier model holds the feature_names_in_ and feature_impartnaces_ properties.

zip creates a zip object of the two properties.

list transfers the zip object to a list of tuples.

sorted by the feature_importances_ as key with lambda



I ran the code here and this way the output was the overall feature importance of the model. My goal is to find the most important feature for each predicted class. Since my X_test has 1800 rows, it would be like finding the feature importance for each row. Is it possible?

@HeloisaRamos It feels like you do not fully understand how a forest model assesses features. Unfortunately, I don't have the skills to explain this. I find it easy to understand when I read the code itself. maybe you too, try this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d5082d32de2797f9594c9477f2810c743560a1f1/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L211
